# difference byproduct

Tags: haskell, syntax

I need to make a function with the signature `diffFolge :: (Integer, Integer) -> [Integer]`, which when applied to the argument pair `(m, n)` (`m, n> 0`) returns a descending list of numbers, the difference between the numbers beeing `n`. The first element of the
Result list is `m`, the last but one element is always greater than `0` and the last element
either `0` or a value strictly less than `0`.

I write it as follows:

```
diffFolge :: (Integer,Integer) -> [Integer]
diffFolge (m,n) = if m > 0 && n > 0 then [m,m-n..n-2*n] else []
```

example

```
input  : diffFolge (5,1)
output : [5,4,3,2,1,0]
```

example

```
input  : diffFolge (5,2)
output :[5,3,1,-1]   ---> This is true by my code
```

However, with the input given in the first example my function returns `[5,4,3,2,1,0,-1]`. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand what you want, but I am guessing this is it:

```
diffFolge  (m,n) | m <= 0    = [m]
                 | otherwise = m : diffFolge (m-n,n)
```

The error in your code is really the last element in your sequence, `n - 2*n`, note
that this is equal to `-n`, so your list does not stop until you get an element which is strictly smaller than `-n`, but in the case where your list includes 0, the next to last element is `0` and the last element is `-n`. To fix this you can simply add `1` to it: `[m,m-n..1-n]`. Then if the list contains `0`, `-n` is excluded, and if it does not contain `0`, the last element is between `0` and `1-n`.

Answer (score 5):

Haskell's `[a..b]` syntax returns a list *including* `b` if possible.

You could use `[m, m-n .. 1-n]`, such that `-n` is excluded.

(BTW, `n-2*n == -n`)

Comment: this is true but for example when i give this as example diffFolge (5,2)  output muss so [5,3,1,-1]

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, it pays to do just a little bit of math. :)

```
diffFolge (m, n) = [m, m-n .. 1-n]
```

Also, it's unusual to use a tuple for multiple arguments to a function in Haskell. I would be more likely to write

```
df m n = [m, m-n .. 1-n]
```

And then, if for some reason I really need a function taking a tuple, I would write:

```
diffFolge = uncurry df
```

Comment: Ah, I missed KennyTM's answer which already pointed this out.

Answer (score 1):

To me it also occurs that you've asserted m>=n
So here's a quick Idea:

```
diffFolge :: (Integer, Integer) -> [Integer]
diffFolge (m,n)
    | m <= 0 || n <= 0 = []
    | n > m = diffFolge (n,m)    -- | Only if you want this case
    | otherwise = takeWhile (>= 0) $ iterate (\x->x-n) m
```